# How do you check if a button has been pressed in html/php

Tags: php, html, button, blogs

I'm trying to build a blog page via HTML and PHP. I have a file called edit.php with two buttons on it, Update and Delete. I want to know how PHP can check to see WHICH button was pressed (Update or delete) so it knows which function to call to either update or delete the post?

i have my html as:

```
<input type="submit" name="command" value="Update" />
<input type="submit" name="command" value="Delete" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you wish to delete this post?')" />
```

and in my php file that processes the posts Create, Delete or Update functions, i have tried using like:

```
if ($_POST && ($_POST['submit'] == "Delete"))
{
  delete();
}
```

but I keep getting errors back saying: Warning: Undefined array key "submit"

If anyone can give me some direction on how one PHP file can see a button value from another PHP file, I would appreciate that!

Comment: `$_POST` is a superglobal and always exists. This check makes no sense.

Comment: Your button's name is `command`, but your code is looking for `submit`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [isset](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) to check if var exists and has any value other than null. You are checking by input type, instead, Check by input field name.

```
<input type="submit" name="update" value="Update" />
<input type="submit" name="delete" value="Delete" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you wish to delete this post?')" />

<?php
    if (isset($_POST['update'])) {
        update();
    }
    elseif (isset($_POST['delete'])) {
        delete();
    }
?>
```

Comment: That doesnt seem to work for me...hmm...

my edit.php file has the buttons coded on it...
im in my insert.php file trying to access the input field name of the buttons from edit.php...

all i have in my insert.php file right now is:

    if (isset($_POST['delete']))
            {
                echo "delete";
            }

but when i save and click my delete button on my edit.php page...it just loads a white screen....so its like its still not recognizing the delete button...

Comment: `Warning: Undefined array key "submit"` is this warning still exists? Have you added two different input names for form submit buttons?

Comment: @Adachi inside Insert.php page use `echo "<pre>";
print_r($_POST);
echo "</pre>";`  to check what you are getting inside POST

Comment: Okay i got it to work, i see that its seeing the button now. Thanks!